# Как вставить в нужный блок поиска найденные данные?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Иметься проблема что при поиске в одном блоке вставляет в второй поиск...
Подскажите где допустил ошибку...

```
initAutocomplete: function() {
            var self = this;
            $(this.options.inputSelector).autocomplete({
                minLength: 3,
                delay: 300,
                autoFocus: true,

                create: function(event, ui){
                    $(self.options.inputSelector).siblings('.ui-front-wrapper').append($('.ui-autocomplete'));
                    $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item){
                        var regex = new RegExp(this.term+"+","gi");
                        var itemName = item.name.replace(regex, "<b>$&</b>");
                        var itemImageHtml = item.image ? '<img src="'+item.image+'"/>': '';
                        return $('<li>')
                            .append( '<a class="id_product" product-id="1"><span class="image">'+itemImageHtml+'</span><span class="title">'+itemName+'</span><span class="price">F 19.6</span></a>')
                            .appendTo(ul);
                    };
                    $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
                        var _self = this;
                        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                            _self._renderItemData(ul, item);
                        });
                     }
                        return ul;
                    };

                },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    this.classList.add('autocomplete-open')
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    this.classList.remove('autocomplete-open');
                },
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var _self = this;
                    var params = !Array.isArray(self.options.searchRequestParams)
                        ? self.options.searchRequestParams
                        : {};
                    params[self.options.searchParamName] = request.term;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: self.options.searchUrl,
                        data: params,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            // if(data.result_url){
                            //     _self.options.allResultsUrl = data.result_url;
                            // }
                            if(data.items){
                                response(data.items);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                },
                messages: {
                    noResults: $t('No search results'),
                    results : function(count) {
                        return '';
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: оффтоп: емнип `response()` должен быть вызван в любом случае, вне завивимости от того, нашлось что или нет

Comment: добавьте сниппет с воспроизводимым примером. и вычистите из кода всякое неиспользуемое типа `messages`. source установите в массив какой-нибудь чтобы работало.

Comment: messages использується, передаеться ответ если не найдено.

Comment: он на суть проблемы влияет или нет? наверное нет, поэтому в печь.

Comment: а причем тут на суть проблемы? проблема не в ответе ж. етот messages ответ тоже нужен, он выводиться если ничего не найдено. и етот ответ выводиться кстати правильно, в каждом поиске выводит.

Comment: есть правила ресурса, которые говорят о том, что к вопросу следует приложить *минимальный* воспроизводимый пример. Если хотите, чтобы вам тут помогли, добавьте сниппет, демонстрирующий проблему с минимально необходимым кодом.